# Get location date format

Tags: php, date, datetime-format, php-carbon

How can I get the date format of the user's country through the Carbon library? For example, the code below brings me the iso formats of that region.

```
 Carbon::now()->locale('tr_TR')->getIsoFormats();
```

This code gives the ISO format used in that region.

```
array:6 [
  "LT" => "HH:mm"
  "LTS" => "HH:mm:ss"
  "L" => "DD.MM.YYYY"
  "LL" => "D MMMM YYYY"
  "LLL" => "D MMMM YYYY HH:mm"
  "LLLL" => "dddd, D MMMM YYYY HH:mm"
]
```

What function should I use so that I can output it as **d.m.Y** instead of "L" => "**DD.MM.YYYY**" instead of ISO format.

Comment: Since Carbon is a child of the PHP DateTime class, couldn't you use the `format` method of DateTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you can check what Carbon does for each ISO format:

https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/Traits/Date.php#L1907

Some of them have equivalent in [DateTime::format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) if this is the format you expect as an output but all won't have an equivalent code. For instance `DateTime::format` has a format for the ordinal `st` / `nd` / `th` but it's only in English, while the ISO format `Do` means day number with ordinal of the current language (can be `inci` for `tr_TR` locale).

This means you can make an approximated mapping of what ISO format is for `DateTime::format`, but this won't be an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `l` as your format like this.

```
$date = Carbon::parse('2022-05-15')->locale('tr_TR');
echo $date->isoFormat('l');
```

Comment: The output of this code is as follows.
15.05.2022
But what I want is the format instead of that date
15.05.2022 => d.m.Y